# Sort a sheet by the value of a column since the second line

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, runtime-error, excel-2007

I want to sort the sheet according to the value(Date) of a column(new-old) from the second row till the end.
I wrote the code, but there's always an error : 1004, sort reference is not valid. Does someone happen to know the solution?
Thank you.
`Workbooks("Task2.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Column("A:CA").Sort key1:=Range("H2"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recorded a macro and I found the answer(it can be simplified) :

```
    Workbooks("Task2.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Workbooks("Task2.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("H1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With Workbooks("Task2.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want `key1:=Range("H:H")?`
I assume column H is your key, rather than a single cell H2.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Column` to `Columns` (typo in posting your code I think)

Then you'll have a runtime error whenever `Worksheets("Data")` is not the currently active worksheet. Your best bet is to avoid this type of errors altogether and *always* work with *qualified ranges*

```
With Workbooks("Task2.xlsm").Worksheets("Data")
    .Column("A:CA").Sort key1:=.Range("H2"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
End with
                              ^^^^
```

Notice the `.` (dot) in front of `Range("H2")` whcih makes it refer *explicitly* to the sheet specified in the `with` clause. Without that, you're using an *unqualified range* whcih refers to the currently active sheet.